# How can I print all outputs of this in newline instead in one line

Tags: linux, terminal, syntax, echo, ubuntu-22.04

I want to get:

- day1
- day2
- day3
- ...
  as output and then input it into a text file

echo -e day{1..360} > dif2.txt
But I didn't got desired result

Comment: If my answer solves your problem it would be really nice if you acknowledged that.

Comment: Hello my friend. Thanks for helping me out. I tried to cast a vote to your answer but I can't  as I have less than 15 reputations here if there is other way please let me know. I am new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo day{1..360}|tr ' ' '\n' >  dif2.txt
```

There's no way to insert newlines into the sequence (without also producing leading spaces for all but the first entry) within the echo.

If whitespace **doesn't** matter you could do:

```
echo -e day{1..360}'\n' >  dif2.txt
```